# How do I write a query to display the customer who claimed maximum amount from an ERD diagram?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is what I wrote but I am not getting the correct answer:

```
select top 1 customer.first_name 
from customer, claims
where customer.id = claims.id
order by claims.amount_of_claim desc
GO
```

[image: ER Diagram]

Comment: Don't use [old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are joining `claim.id` and `customer.id`. Those will never match except by accident. The number on a claims document will never match the number  on your insurance card or policy except by accident.

When you write a query, the table rows are matched based only on the query expressions, not any constraints between tables. This means that the following query will try to match unrelated things:

```
select top 1 customer.first_name 
from customer inner join claims
    on customer.id = claims.id
order by claims.amount_of_claim desc
```

The diagram shows that a Claim is related to a Policy which in turn is related to a customer:

```
Claims(customer_policy_id) -> Customer_Policy(customer_id) -> Customer
```

You'll have to join these 3 tables in your query

```
select top 1 cust.first_name 
from customer cust
    inner join customer_policy pol on cust.id=pol.customer_id
    inner join claims cl on pol.id=cl.customer_policy_id
order by cl.amount_of_claim desc
```

In a relational database relations are represented by *tables*, not foreign key *constraints*. A Foreign Key Constraint is used to ensure that the FK values stored in a table are valid.

On top of that, an ER diagram is *not* a database diagram. The entities and relations shown in an ER diagram are don't map directly to tables. For example, a many-to-many relation between eg `Customer` and `Address` in an ER diagram would have to be translated to a bridge table, `CustomerAddresses(CustomerId,AddressId)`. After all, a table is a relation in relational theory, and `CustomerAddresses` defines the relation between Customer and Address.

Comment: That was a brilliant explanation. I am now getting a correct answer. Thank you so much!!